# Angular indicate that camel case property is always false

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this code and angular indicates that `dahsboard.isCurrentUserOwner` is always false even if it is true.

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('main', function($scope) {
  $scope.dashboards = [{"id":23,"name":"AFM Dashboard","description":"Dashboard displaying the size of the queue for each of the AFM replicated filesets. If the queue_length is > 0 and is a flat line there may be some issue with the replication of the data.","isCurrentUserOwner":true},{"id":24,"name":"GPFS","description":"GPFS state summary dashboard.","isCurrentUserOwner":false},{"id":25,"name":"test1231","description":"testtesttesttest 234567890-1","isCurrentUserOwner":false},{"id":28,"name":"test","description":"test","isCurrentUserOwner":true}];
  $scope.sort = 'asc';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="main">
  <div ng-repeat="dashboard in dashboards">
    <div>{{dashboard|json}}</div>
    <div>{{dahsboard.isCurrentUserOwner ? 'true' : 'false'}}</div>
    <div ng-if="dahsboard.isCurrentUserOwner">
      show
    </div>
    <div ng-if="!dahsboard.isCurrentUserOwner">
      not show
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've also tried to use `dahsboard["is-current-user-owner"]` but it doesn't work, it's still false even if it's true.

Comment: You are going to feel really bad after going through answers.. :)

Comment: I agree with that, but we all did at some point, right ? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a misspelled problem change, `dahsboard` to `dashboard`.

But IMHO try to use `controller as` syntax it's better to access the model that you have inside your controller and in the future will be better to work following the guides that will help you to don't have big problems with scopes.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="main as mainCtrl">
   <div ng-repeat="dashboard in mainCtrl.dashboards">
       <div>{{dashboard|json}}</div>
       <div>{{dashboard.isCurrentUserOwner ? 'true' : 'false'}}</div>
       <div ng-if="dashboard.isCurrentUserOwner">
         show
       </div>
    <div ng-if="!dashboard.isCurrentUserOwner">
        not show
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This should fix the problem you have accessing your model. This is the recommendation using Angular 1.

https://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/

John Papa GuideLine https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide

---

**EDIT**

(Needed 6 characters) Correct `dahsboard` on **all** lines.

Comment: I'm using "controller as" and angular components my code.

Answer (score 1):

Correct `dahsboard` with `dashboard`, it might work.

Corrected code :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="main">
  <div ng-repeat="dashboard in dashboards">
    <div>{{dashboard|json}}</div>
    <div>{{dashboard.isCurrentUserOwner ? 'true' : 'false'}}</div>
    <div ng-if="dashboard.isCurrentUserOwner">
      show
    </div>
    <div ng-if="!dashboard.isCurrentUserOwner">
      not show
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```